# Error in 3 parameter fit when including sigma

Tags: python, scipy, runtime-error, curve-fitting

I obtain an error in the 3-parameter fit using curve-fit when I include the y-axis error = sigma while calling the function.

Without the sigma parameter, the fit gives a good answer, however I would like to include the error in the y-axis while the routine does the least squares estimate.

> RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to
>   function has reached maxfev = 800.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import stats

def func(x,p,q,r):
    #return p*(np.exp(-(q*x)))+r
    return p*(0.56*np.exp(-(q*x))+0.44*np.exp(-x*1E6/1.935))+r

initial=np.array([400,5E5,2])
coeff,pcov=curve_fit(func,time,count,initial,sigma=error)
```

Where error is defined as the sqrt of count with the exception of count=0, where error=0 and not the sqrt of (count=0).

The typical order of the values in the `time` list is 1E-6 and about 600 -> 0 for `count` (exponential).

Comment: I am unable to understand why curve_fit is unable to find the optimum parameters on inclusion of y-axis error and is able to do so otherwise.

Comment: General advice for fitting: normalize your data. So in this case, multiply `time` with 1e6 to get all values around 1. This avoids very large or small (in your case) values that `curve_fit` encounters during fitting, and thus running into floating point limits. Ditto for `count` of course. (I see you have a 1e6 in your function (in the exp); that may or may not solve that issue, but generally, you'll want to avoid that in your fitting function and parameters, and normalize the data beforehand.)

Comment: " count=0, where error=0 and not the sqrt of (count=0)." While this is mathematical correct for Poisson noise/counting statistics, I doubt have a sigma of 0 is a good idea to fit to a fitting routine. Consider a different value for sigma, or remove those points. Since sigma is used as weights, i.e., `weights = 1 / sigma**2` (which obviously breaks down with sigma=0).

Comment: Again, tried both of the above. When error=0, I replaced it with error=1.
As well as normalizing 'time' to 1 by multiplying by 1E6

Comment: Did the normalization bit in the function and the `time` list. No change.

Moreover, I observe that on normalizing  `time`  by multiplying it by 1E6, for some reason the parameters obtained (without including sigma in the curvefit routine) are way off the previous ones. And, on including sigma in the call for curvefit I get the runtime error.

Comment: Could you provide some data that allow to reproduce the issue?!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuij342ki20qilc/sample.npz?dl=0

Here are the required variables as mentioned in the code above. The function used is mentioned above.